# Can't run TextMate from shell with symbolic link in bin (new alpha version) (OSX)

Tags: shell, osx-lion, textmate

I have the latest textmate installed in Applications, the executable is here -

```
/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/MacOS/TextMate
```

I can launch TextMate OK as normal from the icon in Applications

To be able to run from within shell (I use ZSH), I added a symbolic link in /usr/local/bin like so -

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/MacOS/TextMate /usr/local/bin/mate
```

But I try to run mate from shell, I'm getting the following -

```
mate[22695:8403] No Info.plist file in application bundle or no NSPrincipalClass in the Info.plist file, exiting
```

Perhaps I've installed textmate wrong?

Comment: not a programming question. Voting to move to Superuser.com. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You need to symlink the 'mate' CLI, not the TextMate file.

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/mate /usr/local/bin/mate
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @shellter but…

I don't know if it works in `zsh` but TextMate has its own CLI wrapper (`mate`) that you can install from Preferences -> Terminal. It has worked well for years and is very convenient:

```
Usage: mate [-awl<number>rdnhv] [file ...]
Options:
 -a, --async            Do not wait for file to be closed by TextMate.
 -w, --wait             Wait for file to be closed by TextMate.
 -l, --line <number>    Place caret on line <number> after loading file.
 -r, --recent           Add file to Open Recent menu.
 -d, --change-dir       Change TextMates working directory to that of the file.
 -n, --no-reactivation  After edit with -w, do not re-activate the calling app.
 -h, --help             Show this information.
 -v, --version          Print version information.

If multiple files are given, a project is created consisting of these
files, -a is then default and -w will be ignored (e.g. "mate *.tex").

By default mate will not wait for the file to be closed
except when used as filter:
 ls *.tex|mate|sh      -w implied
 mate -|cat -n         -w implied (read from stdin)

An exception is made if the command is started as something which ends
with "_wait". So to have a command with --wait as default, you can
create a symbolic link like this:
 ln -s mate mate_wait
```

Another cheap option would be to add an alias to whatever `~/.*rc` file `zsh` executes at startup similar to this one for `bash`:

```
alias mate='open -a textmate'
```